# Is caching always secure over HTTPS?

Tags: caching, ssl, https, proxy, cache-control

People recommend using `Cache-Control: private` if the resource is sensitive, to avoid exposing sensitive information in the proxy.

But if the resource can only be requested over HTTPS, aren't the resources cached in the proxy also SSL-encrypted?

Comment: The data is encrypted between the client and proxy, and between the proxy and server. But the proxy decodes it and re-encodes it.

Comment: Can't the proxy just "pass around" the SSL packets?

Comment: It depends on the type of proxy and how the client uses it.

Comment: Which type of proxy will encrypt/decrypt? For example: web accelerator, ISP, typical forward proxy?